# How to define two servers on different IPs in nginx?

Tags: nginx, virtualhost

Here is the problem: I have two domains which have pointed to two available IPs on a server.
Say:

siteone.com pointed to 1.2.3.4 
sitetwo.com pointed to 1.2.3.5

What I did to configure nginx vhosts was to put

```
server {
        listen    site1.com:80; # 
        server_name   site1.com www.site1.com;
```

on vhost1 file and

```
server {
        listen    site2.com:80; # 
        server_name   site2.com www.site2.com;
```

on a (separate) vhost2 file. The two vhost files are exact replicates expect the site1 and site2 paths, of course. And vhost1 is working well on its own.

However after restarting nginx I get this error:

> Restarting nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax
>   is ok [emerg]: bind() to 1.2.3.5:80 failed (99: Cannot assign
>   requested address) configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test
>   failed

When I put

```
server {
        listen   *:80; # 
        server_name   site2.com www.site2.com;
```

On site2 vhost, the nginx restarts without error but does not render pages on site2 path.

I'm confused and appreciate your help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
server {
    listen    1.2.3.4:80; # 
    server_name   site1.com www.site1.com;
    ...
}

server {
    listen    1.2.3.5:80; # 
    server_name   site2.com www.site2.com;
    ...
}
```

Comment: You beat me to it!

Comment: Do you mean putting both directives on vhost1 file?

Comment: @alfish: no matter. You can put it in anywhere you want (as long as it is included in the main configuration file).

Comment: After doing this, I get the same error:"Restarting nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
[emerg]: bind() to 1.2.3.5:80 failed (99: Cannot assign requested address)configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed" . How can I check that 1.2.3.5 is really usable, as my ISP claims?

Comment: `sudo /sbin/ip addr sh`?

Comment: @quanta the command's output includes something equivalent to:  inet 1.2.3.4/29 brd 1.2.3.9 scope global eth0

Comment: Where did you get the 1.2.3.5 IP address? `ping 1.2.3.5`?

Comment: Oh my bad. It turned out that I had not activated 1.2.3.5 in networking configs. Sorry guys. It works now by adding: auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
address 1.2.3.5
gateway 1.2.3.3
netmask 255.255.255.248 to /etc/network/interfaces